# the js code was working in html file. but not working at js file

Tags: javascript

This JS code works properly in the .html file, but not working in .js file(external file). I would like to apply this JS code to each page, so planning to move it to .js file
can anyone help me? I appreciate your time.

in .html file (this code working)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        navbar_height = document.querySelector(".navbar").offsetHeight;
        document.body.style.paddingTop = navbar_height + "px";
    });
    
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
        var lastScrollTop = 0;
        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            var st = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if (st > lastScrollTop) {
                jQuery("nav.navbar:not(.navbar-transparent)").slideUp();
            } else {
                jQuery("nav.navbar:not(.navbar-transparent)").slideDown();
            }
            lastScrollTop = st;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

in .js file (this code not working)

```
$(document).addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    navbar_height = document.querySelector(".navbar").offsetHeight;
    document.body.style.paddingTop = navbar_height + "px";
});

$(window).addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        var st = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (st > lastScrollTop) {
            jQuery("nav.navbar:not(.navbar-transparent)").slideUp();
        } else {
            jQuery("nav.navbar:not(.navbar-transparent)").slideDown();
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
    });
});
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in console? Have you included jQuery? Are you adding the `js` file correctly into the `html` file?

Comment: Can you not see the difference between `document` and `$(document)`? Same for `window` and `$(window)`

Comment: @Phil, Thank you for your help, I thought I must change the document to $(document). Because other code I found in .js file about hiding the navbar when scroll, started from $(document)

Comment: I bet that other code didn't try and use `$(document).addEventListener()`. `$(...)` returns a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/). They do not have methods like `addEventListener()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

on line number two, there is syntex error. It shall be

```
let navbar_height
```